# Leaving the US, returning to the UK, and then going to Canada quickly afterwards

Tags: usa, canada

Ok, so I know that I have to leave the US within 90 days on the VWP (I'm here now and my ticket back to the UK is July 25th). Canada, however allows me to stay upto 6 months on my UK passport... and I'd rather be there than the UK.
If I leave the US, fly to the UK (therefore leaving the USA entirely), and then a week later fly into Canada, will I have any issues?
..And 4-5 months down the line, I'll probably travel from Canada to Washington where my girlfriend lives. I certainly won't be attempting to enter the US for at least 4 months. 
Any problems I'm likely to face?

Comment: You don't have to go to the UK. You can spend 90 days in the US, then six months in Canada, and then enter the US again on the VWP.  Of course there's always a chance you'd be denied entry, but a one-week stay in the UK, *six months before your attempt to reenter,* will not significantly affect the probability one way or another.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for your comments, I'm a bit confused though as this: "Under the VWP, time spent in Canada, Mexico, and adjacent islands counts towards the maximum of 90 days stay allowed under the program"... I think, basically means that I'd be overstaying my 90 days.

Comment: @MattB That rule isn't applied for *long* stays in Canada. If you were six months in Canada you would probably get a new entry under VWP. However...

Comment: What are you doing in Canada for six months? How are you supporting yourself while you are there? What is the purpose of your visit? I ask because both Canadian and US immigration will want to know.

Comment: You wouldn't be overstaying because you wouldn't be in the US when your period of admission ends.  The law states that when you apply for admission after going to (e.g.) Canada, you may be admitted for the remainder of the original 90-day period. (Note "may": it's at the officer's discretion.) If the original period has already lapsed then this provision ofthe law cannot apply. If you've been out of the country for (nearly) six months, there's no way you'd be suspected of using a visa run to extend your stay in the US. The issues you should be worrying about are those raised by @DJClayworth.

Comment: @phoog `If you've been out of the country for (nearly) six months, there's no way you'd be suspected of using a visa run to extend your stay in the US.` I disagree. The fact that a person is not returning to his home country would and should be of concern to a CBP officer because a requirement for US visa and by extension ESTA is `You must also show you maintain your residence abroad, which you have no intention of abandoning, and that you have other binding ties which  and that you have other binding ties which will ensure your return abroad at the end of the visit`

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie that is the issue raised by DJClayworth. My point is that a short trip to the UK before a six-month stay in Canada is not going to change an immigration officer's evaluation of *either* issue. I agree that theplan is risky with respect to denial of admission, but that risk is unrelated to the 90-day limit, nor to the "non-resetting of the clock" commonly cited with respect to presence in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

> If I leave the US, fly to the UK (therefore leaving the USA entirely), and then a week later fly into Canada, will I have any issues?

Nobody can tell definitively if you will have any issues. People with similar travel patters have been *allowed* in, and similarly some have been *turned away*.

It depends on the immigration agent at the border. That said 3 months in USA, 1 week in UK, and then a flight to Canada is not strange **however** if you indicate to the Canadian officer you're looking to spend about 5 months in Canada, it would clearly show the UK is not exactly your home base any more and your ties to it are tenuous, e.g. no job there, apartment etc.

And finally even if Canada let's you in, chances are high you will be turned away by the US CBP at the border. In eight months you would have spent one week in your home country UK, that's not typical coupled with a girlfriend in the USA? Very high probability you get turned away in these times.

What you're trying to do is akin to satisfying the letter of the law (by completely leaving the American continent for one week) while violating the spirit of it, if you get my drift.

My sources of reference would be numerous [Canada Border Security](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=canada+border+security) shows on YouTube and extensive immigration experience.